# BeanUtils.copyProperties() or use setter() for copying values

Tags: java, javabeans

I am just trying to find which approach is better for copying data from one object to the other. Please find the below code

`Bean1`:

```
private int id;
private int rollnumber;
private String name;
private String department;

//constructor and getter setter
```

`Bean2`:

```
private int id;
private int rollnumber;
private String name;
private String dob;
private String department;

//constructor and getter setter
```

I have these two classes. Now, the main() is,

```
public static void main(String...args){
        Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1(1,1001,"","");
        Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Copying using setter
        bean2.setDepartment(bean1.getDepartment());
        bean2.setDob(null);
        bean2.setId(bean1.getId());
        bean2.setName(bean1.getName());
        bean2.setRollnumber(bean1.getRollnumber());
        System.out.println("total time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
    }
```

In this approach, the time difference is very less compared to the below code, which is using **BeanUtils.copyProperties**.

```
public static void main(String...args){
        Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1(1,1001,"","");
        Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2);

        System.out.println("total time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
    }
```

Anyone please suggest me which approach is better in an **organization project.**

*Thanks in Advance !!!*

Comment: the best approach is store your **important entities using `constructor` and rest using `setter`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think for task such simple and well-defined, it would be prudent to
  manually setting the attributes rather than using
  `BeanUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2);`. You will have more control at your disposal.
- The `Apache` library uses reflection, so it would be much slower than
  your manual approach.

.

Comment: thank you for the reply. and if i have more properties like 100 or 100, that time which would be better? BeanUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2); or setter?

Comment: Please answer **which one is better**? in case of many properties?

Comment: See, copying without reflection is always going to out-perform copying with reflection. But the time difference would go down as the number of properties increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2);
```

Uses Reflection for copying the properties of bean1 to bean2 which can be costly.
Copying the attributes using setter will make you right more code but will be more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the reply. and cost is measured in time? or memory allocation?

Comment: The cost here is measured in time.